# Twitter user that tweets all messages containing a hashtag

Tags: twitter, account-management

I am using Echofon for Mac and wonder how can I get, through Growl, all new messages based on some hashtag. In the options it does not seem to be possible.

Another option would be to get new tweets from a user that tweets only about a certain hashtag, is it possible to create such user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a so called Twitter Bot which will tweet everything containing a certain hashtag.

There is a really good [tutorial on this](http://www.digeratimarketing.co.uk/2009/09/23/how-to-make-a-twitter-bot-with-no-coding/) here.

Comment: great idea! I read it and seems to be quite complicated for me :(

Comment: I know, maybe you can find some other resources, google for Twitter Bot!